# Hibernate Validator 5 version compatibility with Hibernate 3.5

Tags: java, hibernate, compatibility, hibernate-validator, hibernate3

Is it safe to use the `Hibernate Validator 5.0.1` with `Hibernate 3.5.4`? From what I've read it should not be a problem and I'm not running into any errors so far (i.e. application compiles, runs and tests pass), but I'm not sure if they fit well together.

Related Hibernate & JPA libs (inside `/WEB-INF/libs`):

```
hibernate3.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.5.4-Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.5.4-Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.4-Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-5.0.1.Final.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

FYI:

```
Tomcat 7.0.39
Spring 3.0.3
PostgreSQL 9.2
Flyway 2.1.1
BoneCP 0.7.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be fine with using Bean Validation 1.1/Hibernate Validator 5.0.1; Hibernate ORM depends on the Bean Validation API only, and BV 1.1 is compatible with BV 1.0.

I recommend to check the Hibernate Validator [migration guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateValidatorMigrationGuide) to see whether any of the issues listed there might affect you (for instances changes around logging and the usage of Java 6).